# Diff between bit and byte, and exact meaning of byte

Tags: storage

This is just basic theoretical question. so I read that a bit consist of 0 or 1. and a  byte consists of 8 bits. and in 8 bit we can store 2^8 nos.

similarly in 10 bits we store 2^10 (1024). but then why do we say that 1024 is 1 kilo bytes, its actually 10 bits which just 1.25 byte to be exact.

please share some knowledge on it

just a concrete explanation.

Comment: 1 kilobyte is 1024 byte, not 1024 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Bit means like there are 8 bits in 1 byte, bit is the smallest unit of any storage or you can say the system and 8 bits sums up to 1 byte.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

A bit, short for binary digit, is the smallest unit of measurement used in computers for information storage. A bit is represented by a 1 or a 0 with the value true or false, also known as on or off. A single byte of information, also known as an octet, is made up of eight bits. The size, or amount of information stored, distinguishes a bit from a byte.
A kilobit is 1,000 bits, but it is designated as 1024 bits in the binary system due to the amount of space required to store a kilobit using common operating systems and storage schemes. Most people, however, think of kilo as referring to 1,000 in order to remember what a kilobit is. A kilobyte then, would be 1,000 bytes.

Comment: so if i infer that in 1 kb, which is equal to 1024 bits, i can store 2^1024 combinations. am i correct? this seems a very big no  to me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).